# JavaFX Canvas: Draw a shape exclusively within another shape

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, javafx-8, shapes

I'm currently developing a game in Java, and I've been trying to figure out how to draw a shape (e.g. a circle) to the canvas, on top of a different shape (e.g. a square), but to only draw the parts of the circle which are intersecting the square, similar to a clipping mask between layers in Photoshop.

I've tried using [`GraphicsContext.clearRect()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#clearRect-double-double-double-double-) to clear the areas where the bottom shape is not, but that removes the background.

The code below produces this result:

[image: actual result]

However, this is the result I desire:

[image: desired result]

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleWithinSquareTest extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        int width = 200;
        int height = 200;
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            final int bgCellSize = 8;
            final int x = 100;
            final int y = 100;
            double angle = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                /* Draw checkered background */
                gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                gc.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
                boolean odd = false;
                for (int y = 0; y < height; y += bgCellSize) {
                    odd = !odd;
                    for (int x = odd ? 0 : bgCellSize; x < width; x += bgCellSize * 2) {
                        gc.fillRect(x, y, bgCellSize, bgCellSize);
                    }
                }
                /* Draw square */
                gc.setFill(Color.BLUE);
                gc.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
                /* Draw circle */
                gc.save();
                angle += 5;
                if (angle >= 360) {
                    angle = 0;
                }
                Rotate r = new Rotate(angle, x, y);
                gc.setTransform(r.getMxx(), r.getMyx(), r.getMxy(), r.getMyy(), r.getTx(), r.getTy());
                gc.setFill(Color.RED);
                gc.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
                gc.restore();
            }
        };
        timer.start();

        Group root = new Group(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [clipping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html), add next code before setTransform:

```
gc.beginPath();
gc.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
gc.closePath();
gc.clip();
```

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks! I can't believe I missed this. That's much simpler of a solution than I was expecting. Also, I notice that it still produces the desired result if I comment out `gc.beginPath()` and `gc.closePath()`?

Comment: Yep, it will work as you have an empty path. Just don't forget to return them back if you start using other paths in the same graphic context.